# Передача данных с использованием сокетов

Tags: c++, сокет, tcp

Пишу на linux приложение с использование сокетов на основе TCP. 
На клиенте ,на сервере одинаковая структура:

```
struct Test
{
    uint32_t id;
    char str[48];
};
```

На сервере для принятия данных код выглядит так:

```
uint32_t a = 0;
Test post;
 while (1)
    {
        if ((sock = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL)) > 0)
        {
            recv(sock, &a, sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
            cout<<a<<endl;
            recv(sock, &post, sizeof(Test), 0);
            cout<<post.id<<endl;
        }
        close(sock);
    }
```

На клиенте так:

```
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(2);
    }
    int choice;
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice==1)
    {
        uint32_t a = 25;
        send(sock, &a, sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
    }
    else
    {
        Test post;
        post.id = 5;
        string message = "message";
        strcpy(post.str, message.c_str());
        send(sock, &post, sizeof(Test), 0);

    }
```

Если отправляю `uint32_t` получаю(понятно):

```
a:25
post.id:0
```

Если отправляю структуру,получаю :

```
a:5
post.id:0
```

Как исправить,чтобы в `post.id` записывалось 5(из посланной структуры от клиента) а не 0?

Comment: `send(sock, &post, sizeof(uint32_t)` - посылаете (и получаете) только 4 байта. Что вы хотите получить? Ну и практически полное отсутствие ошибок.

Comment: @VTT, хочу чтобы при одном условии записывалось значение в `a` ,при другом записывалось в поле структуры.Код исправил

Comment: Так а что вам мешает так сделать?

Comment: @VTT, то, что посылая структуру данные некорректно записывются.Это условие в коде обязательно

Comment: Что значит некорректно? Какое условие?

Comment: @VTT,последние 7 строк моего вопроса, условие в коде клиента `choice`

Comment: Там нигде не написано, что из этого считается некорректным. Так условие у вас на клиенте. Отправляйте `choice` на сервер, чтобы тот знал, что ему должно прийти дальше.

Comment: @VTT, 3 дня мучений закончились.Вы мне очень помогли.Спасибо огромное